# Copy text of a field into another automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to copy the text entered in a field (whether it was typed in, pasted or from browser auto-filler) and paste it in another field either at the same time or as soon as the user changes to another field.

If the user deletes the text in field_1, it should also get automatically deleted in field_2.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

function onchange() {
var box1 = document.getElementById('field_1');
var box2 = document.getElementById('field_2');
box2.value = box1.value;
}
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you bind the `onchange` event to anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are almost there... The function is correct, you just have to assign it to the `change` event of the input:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        function onchange() {
            //Since you have JQuery, why aren't you using it?
            var box1 = $('#field_1');
            var box2 = $('#field_2');
            box2.val(box1.val());
        }
        $('#field_1').on('change', onchange);
    });
```

Comment: @DanielPanic can you advise how it could be optimized?

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.textBox1').on('change', function() {
   $('.textBox2').val($(this).val());
 }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="textBox1"/>
<input type="text" class="textBox2"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using jQuery, it is very easy - you need just register the right function on the right event :)

Here's the code:

```
<input id="foo" />
<input id="bar" />

$(function(){
    var $foo = $('#foo');
    var $bar = $('#bar');
    function onChange() {
        $bar.val($foo.val());
    };
    $('#foo')
        .change(onChange)
        .keyup(onChange);
});
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/6khr8e2b/

Comment: Additional bonus is that you use both events `change` and `keyup`

Answer (score 0):

Call `onchange()` method on the first element `onblur`

```
<input type="text" id="field_1" onblur="onchange()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try with keyup event

```
 <input type="text" id="box_1"/>
<input type="text" id="box_2"/>
$('#box_1').keyup(function(){

$('#box_2').val($(this).val());

})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#field_1').on('change', function (e) {
       $('#field_2').val($('#field_1').val());
    });
});
```

Heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/otwk92gp/

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the first input to an event. Something like this would work:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#a").change(function(){
        var a = $("#a").val();
        $("#b").val(a);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="a" />
<input type="text" id="b" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the value of the second field is updated as the same time that the first one, you could handle this with a timeout.

Each time a key is pressed, it will execute the `checkValue` function on the next stack of the execution. So the value of the `field1` in the `DOM` will already be updated when this function is called.

```js
var $field1 = $("#field_1");
var $field2 = $("#field_2");

$field1.on("keydown",function(){
   setTimeout(checkValue,0); 
});

var v2 = $field2.val();
var checkValue = function(){
    var v1 = $field1.val();
    if (v1 != v2){
        $field2.val(v1);
        v2 = v1;
    }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field_1" value=""/><br/>
<input id="field_2" value=""/>
```