# jquery copy text from select options into another automatically input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i want  copy text from select options  into another automatically input , i have find this :  `http://jsfiddle.net/6khr8e2b/`  but i cannot change it.

i want do this:

```
<select >
<option value="0">AAAA</option>
<option value="1">BBBB</option>
</select>

<select >
<option value="0">CCCC</option>
<option value="1">DDDD</option>
</select>

<input type="text" >
```

i will have two select and one  input
when i chose  on selects AAAA  and DDDD  i want that in input value automatically type:  AAAA DDDD

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy text of a field into another automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351515/copy-text-of-a-field-into-another-automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript Solution**

```js
const selects = document.querySelectorAll('#select_1, #select_2');

const selectOne = selects[0];
const selectTwo = selects[1];

const input = document.getElementById('input_1');

Array.from(selects).forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', () => {
    input.value = `${selectOne.options[selectOne.selectedIndex].textContent} ${selectTwo.options[selectTwo.selectedIndex].textContent}`;
  });
});
```

```html
<select id="select_1">
  <option value="0">AAAA</option>
  <option value="1">BBBB</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2">
  <option value="0">CCCC</option>
  <option value="1">DDDD</option>
</select>

<input id="input_1" type="text">
```

**jQuery Solution**

```js
$(function() {
  const $selects = $('#select_1, #select_2');
  
  const $selectOne = $selects.eq(0);
  const $selectTwo = $selects.eq(1);

  const $input = $('#input_1');

  $selects.on('change', () => {
    $input.val(`${$selectOne.find(':selected').text()} ${$selectTwo.find(':selected').text()}`);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select_1">
  <option value="0">AAAA</option>
  <option value="1">BBBB</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2">
  <option value="0">CCCC</option>
  <option value="1">DDDD</option>
</select>

<input id="input_1" type="text">
```

Comment: Can you try again. I just made an adjustment.

Comment: now working, but how do that it work only for id="select_1"  id="select_2" id="input_1"

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you rephrase that?

Comment: @Geo1313 I think I understand now. Can you check my update and see if that addressed your question?

Comment: Check my latest update. I've provided a jQuery solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

it will helpful to you

```js
function getinput(){

var val="";
val=$("#select_1 option:selected").text()+ " "+$("#select_2 option:selected").text()
$("#input_1").val(val);
}
$(function(){
   $(".select").change(function(){
      var val="";
      val=$("#select_1 option:selected").text()+ " "+$("#select_2 option:selected").text()
      $("#input_1").val(val);

   });
    $(".select").trigger("change");
})
```

```css
select{
width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  class="select"  id="select_1">
<option value="0">AAAA</option>
<option value="1">BBBB</option>
</select>

<select class="select" id="select_2">
<option value="0">CCCC</option>
<option value="1">DDDD</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="input_1" >
```

Comment: can do same without onchange="getinput()"

Comment: how can i add Third <select  class="select"  id="select_3">

Comment: @Geo1313 ` val=$("#select_1 option:selected").text()+ " "+$("#select_2 option:selected").text()+" "+$("#select_3 option:selected").text()`