# How do i move text within an input form to a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, function

I'm making a to do list website which moves the entered things in the form box to the div on the right side.

Here is a picture of the site:
[To do list site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIoId.png)

i'm trying to get it to function as when you enter "clean room" into the form box, it would then appear as text in the div on the right.

I'm sure there is java script i need to use can someone point me in the correct direction?

My HTML and CSS:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left h2 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.left form {
    border: 4px solid rgb(102, 181, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.left form input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: none;
}

.box {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 234, 176);
    width: 600px;
    height: 68vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="text/javascript" href="javascript.js">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My to do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>To do list</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <h2>Please Enter your things to do here..</h2>
            <form action="">
                <input type="text">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="box">

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: `input.addEventListener('change', () => div.innerText = input.value)`

Comment: this might be useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351515/copy-text-of-a-field-into-another-automatically

Answer (score 0):

This is probably far from a Todo but it'll give you some clarification of what to do.

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
let inputTodo = document.getElementById('inputTodo');

const inputTodoHandler = (event) => {
  if(event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
     addTodo(event.target.value);
     event.target.value = '';
     return false;
  }
}

const addTodo = (todo) => {
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = todo;
  box.appendChild( p );
}

inputTodo.addEventListener('keydown', inputTodoHandler );
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left h2 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.left form {
    border: 4px solid rgb(102, 181, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.left form input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: none;
}

.box {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 234, 176);
    width: 600px;
    height: 68vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="text/javascript" href="javascript.js">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My to do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>To do list</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <h2>Please Enter your things to do here..</h2>
            <form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
                <input type="text" id="inputTodo">
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="box">

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few concepts you should look up:

- how to assign a DOM element to a variable with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) or other methods:

  ```
  const input = document.querySelector('input')
  const div = document.querySelector('.box')
  ```
- events and event listeners. In your case you are going to have to listen to the changes made to your `<input>` element with [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

  ```
  input.addEventListener('change', callback)
  ```
- how to modify the content of a DOM element with [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText):

  ```
  div.innerText = input.value
  ```

---

And then, putting it all together

```
const input = document.querySelector('input')
const div = document.querySelector('.box')
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    div.innerText = input.value
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way to give you a direction of thoughts is roughly to use event listener for key  pressed in the input field.

Also since you want to create some kind of list, you need to add input new value to destination content once Enter key was pressed, dividing lines with End-of-line character.

Note: You don't need to use the form tag here as form usually used for exchange data with server side scripts.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('src_txt');
var dest = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
el.addEventListener('keypress', function(ev) {
 if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
  dest.innerText += (el.value + "\n");
 }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(27, 27, 27);
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left h2 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

#src_txt {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: 4px solid rgb(102, 181, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.box {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 234, 176);
    width: 600px;
    height: 68vh;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="text/javascript" href="javascript.js">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My to do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>To do list</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <h2>Please Enter your things to do here..</h2>
                <input type="text" id='src_txt'>
        </div>

        <div class="box">

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do the trick.  The event.preventDefault() stops the form from being submitted to your server.

```js
function moveit(){

event.preventDefault();
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var input = inputs[0].value;

var box = document.getElementById('box');

var before = box.innerHTML
var after = before + '<br/>'+ input;


box.innerHTML=after;



}
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    background-color: pink;
   
}

h1 {
    font-size: 5.5vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.left h2 {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.left form {
    border: 4px solid rgb(102, 181, 255);
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.left form input {
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    border: none;
}

#box {
    border: 5px solid black;
    border-radius: 7px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 234, 176);
    width: 600px;
    height: 68vh;
    color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>My to do list</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>To do list</h1>
    </header>
    <section class="main">
        <div class="left">
            <h2>Please Enter your things to do here..</h2>
            <form onsubmit="moveit();">
                <input type="text" ><br/>
                <input type='submit' value='submit' >
                
            </form>
        </div>

        <div id="box">

        </div>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

use the Database system in your Website using sql or any server that stores the info in cloud that store/edit/delete and acess the database in your right/desired location